# Sharpcap обработка полученного пакета

Tags: c#

Помогите привести данные пакета `(hex1)` в читабельный вид и вывести в `richTextBox1` . В хекс виде выдает все данные нормально , но как только пытаюсь перевести в ASCII или Unicode половину данных либо пропадает либо приложение зависает .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PacketDotNet;
using SharpPcap;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace snif
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CaptureDeviceList deviceList = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;
        ICaptureDevice captureDevice;

        string data;
        string hex1 = "";
        string hex;
        int l;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (deviceList.Count == 0)
                this.comboBox1.Text = "Устройств не обнаружено";
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i != deviceList.Count; ++i)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add((i + 1).ToString() + "   " + deviceList[i].Description);
                }
            }
        }

        private void start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            captureDevice = deviceList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
            int readTimeoutMilliseconds = 1000;
            captureDevice.Open(DeviceMode.Promiscuous, readTimeoutMilliseconds);
            captureDevice.OnPacketArrival += new PacketArrivalEventHandler(Program_OnPacketArrival);
            captureDevice.StartCapture();
            label1.Text = "Статус : Подключен";
        }

        private void stop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (captureDevice.Started)
            {
                captureDevice.StopCapture();
                captureDevice.Close();
                label1.Text = "Статус : Отключен";
            }
        }

        private void clear(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void Program_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
        {
            Packet packet = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            var tcpPacket = TcpPacket.GetEncapsulated(packet);
            var ipPacket = IpPacket.GetEncapsulated(packet);
            if (tcpPacket != null && ipPacket != null)
            {
                DateTime time = e.Packet.Timeval.Date;
                int len = e.Packet.Data.Length;

                var srcIp = ipPacket.SourceAddress.ToString();
                var dstIp = ipPacket.DestinationAddress.ToString();

                var srcPort = tcpPacket.SourcePort.ToString();
                var dstPort = tcpPacket.DestinationPort.ToString();

                if (srcIp == "188.93.63.168")
                {
                    hex = BitConverter.ToString(tcpPacket.PayloadData);
                      hex = hex.Replace("-", "");

                    l = hex.Length;

                    if (l > 0)
                    {
                        string sum = hex[l - 2].ToString() + hex[l - 1].ToString();
                        if (sum == "00")
                        {
                            hex1 += hex;
                            this.Invoke(new Action(datapaket));
                        }
                        hex1 += hex;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        public void datapaket()
        {

            richTextBox1.AppendText(hex1);
          //  richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("3E3C", "3E" + "\n" + "3C");
            hex1 = "";
        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        }

    }
```

Comment: _и вывести в richTextBox1_